# Problem after installing wxruby, no suitable image found, on Mac OS 10.6 & 10.7 & Red-Hat

Tags: user-interface, rubygems, wxruby

### I am trying to install wxruby. I've tried gem install wxruby, gem install wxruby-19-2.0.0 downloading the wxruby-2.0.1-universal-darwin-9.gem. I tried the arch -i386 ruby change and got an error on arch of unsupported architecture (on Snow Leopard and Lion).

I've tried it on Mac OS X Lion and Snow Leopard. Under ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. And also tried on Linux (RED-HAT). All gave the same error. When I tried to compile it I got a swig version error which I fixed and then ton's of errors in the code of not finding size_t and other items. I tried a new install of wxwidgets (on Snow Leopard) and that did not help.

It always installs fine but when I run some test code I get:
/Users/jwright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/jwright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-universal-darwin-9/lib/wxruby2.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Users/jwright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-universal-darwin-9/lib/wxruby2.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper - /Users/jwright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-universal-darwin-9/lib/wxruby2.bundle
    from /Users/jwright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /Users/jwright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/wxruby-2.0.1-universal-darwin-9/lib/wx.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jwright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in`require'
    from /Users/jwright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/jwright/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in`require'
    from ./test_wxruby.rb:3:in `'

It does the same thing when I use irb
require 'rubygems'
require 'wx'

Please help. I really want to use this.  My other cross-platform option is JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue. Starting with Snow Laopard, OSX ships with 64-bit ruby set as default. And installed gem is 32-bit. In order to fix this, add following shebang to your ruby script (it will force script to be executed under 32-bit ruby):

```
#!/usr/bin/env arch -i386 ruby

require 'rubygems'
# This will work thanks to arch -i386
require 'wx'
```

Comment: @iktorn I don't have a clean lion install right now to test. Why it is not working? `arch` not starting correct ruby interpreter, weWidgets can't compile or something else?